# Inserção de dados no banco, através de um Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

estou criando um projeto que precisa criar usuarios, tenho um metodo pronto funcionando porém estou tentando colocar uma forma de exibir em um dialog.

criei um uma tela com um recycler view para exibir a lista de usuarios, e ao clicar no botao adicionar ele  chama esse dialog com os campos, e ao clicar em adicionar no dialog ele insere no banco os valores. 
entretanto nos logs nao aponta nenhum erro, porém nao acontece nada, e o metodo que implementei esta baseado no que eu mesmo montei em uma view separada.

```
public class Admin_Usuarios  extends Activity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_usuarios);
        EntradaApp.setContext(getApplicationContext());



    }// fim oncreate



  public void adicionarUsuarios(View view){
    CadastroUsuario_dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager());

  }
}
```

esta e a class que chama o dialog

```
public class CadastroUsuario_dialog extends DialogFragment{
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "Adicionar_UsuarioPreferences";
    String tipo;
    String senha;
    String nome;
    String usuario;
    String email;
    String id_tipo;
    Button btcriar;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_adicionar_usuario, null);


        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity() ,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        List<String> tipos = new ArrayList<String>();
        tipos.add("Administração");
        tipos.add("Comum");


        Spinner spin1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.sptipo_usuario);




        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tipos);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = arrayAdapter;
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spin1.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int posicao, long id) {
                //pega nome pela posição
                tipo = parent.getItemAtPosition(posicao).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });



        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(view).create();


}


    public static void show(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("editar_carro");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        CadastroUsuario_dialog frag = new CadastroUsuario_dialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        frag.show(ft, "Ajuda");
    }




}
```

este é o dialog implementado

```
public void adicionarusuario(View view ) {
        EditText etid_tipo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etid1);
        EditText etnome = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etnome1);
        EditText etusuario = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etusuario1);
        EditText etsenha = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etsenha1);
        EditText etemail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etemail1);


        nome = etnome.getText().toString();
        email = etemail.getText().toString();
        usuario = etusuario.getText().toString();
        senha = etsenha.getText().toString();
        id_tipo = etid_tipo.getText().toString();


        Usuarios_Model u = new Usuarios_Model();

        u.setNome(nome);
        u.setEmail(email);
        u.setSenha(senha);
        u.setUsuario(usuario);
        u.setTipo_usuario(tipo);
        u.setId(Integer.parseInt(id_tipo));
        List<Usuarios_Model> ls = new ArrayList<>();
        ls.add(u);
        new DAO_usuario().Insert(ls);



    }
```

DAO do sistema

```
public class DAO_usuario extends DAO_Principal<Usuarios_Model> {
    @Override
    protected ContentValues getContentValues(Usuarios_Model object) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(("id"), object.getId());
        contentValues.put(("nome"), object.getNome());
        contentValues.put(("usuario"), object.getUsuario());
        contentValues.put(("senha"), object.getSenha());
        contentValues.put(("email"), object.getEmail());
        contentValues.put(("tipo_usuario"), object.getTipo_usuario());
        return  contentValues;
    }

    @Override
    protected Usuarios_Model FillObject(Cursor cursor) {
        Usuarios_Model usuarios_model = new Usuarios_Model();
        usuarios_model.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
        usuarios_model.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
        usuarios_model.setUsuario(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("usuario")));
        usuarios_model.setSenha(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("senha")));
        usuarios_model.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
        usuarios_model.setTipo_usuario(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tipo_usuario")));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getTable() {
        return "Usuario";
    }
    @Override
    public void Insert(List<Usuarios_Model> list) {
        super.Insert(list);
    }

    @Override
    public void Erase(){
        super.Erase();

    }

    public void Erase(int id, String condicao) {
        super.Erase(id, condicao);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Usuarios_Model> ListAll() {
        return super.ListAll();
    }
```

em uma view a parte funciona, entretanto ao colocar no dialog acontece algum erro e não estou encontrando. Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Diga-me se entendi, você quer adicionar utilizadores a partir de uma Dialog certo?

Comment: isso, gostaria de fazer o dialog funcionar da mesma forma que a activity para inserir dados

Comment: Entendi como faço funcionar , estancio antes e nao no dialog em si
, ao chamar o método eu intancio as variaveis com final, para que na hora que eu chamar o dialog com os valores eu apenas receba os valores e ao clicar no adicionar ele fecha o dialog  com um dismiss e recebe todos os valores da mesma forma que na view!!

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo a pergunta que criei.

intanciei valores fora e deixei apenas carregar o layout no dialog

```
public void ExibeDialog(){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_adicionar_usuario);

    final Button btcriar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btcriar);

    final EditText etnome = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.etnomed);

    final EditText etusuario = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etusuariod);

    btcriar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            u.setNome(nome);
            u.setEmail(email);

            List<Usuarios_Model> ls = new ArrayList<>();
            ls.add(u);
            new DAO_usuario().Insert(ls);

            dialog.dismiss();

            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());// " finish(); + startActivity funcionam como um refresh

            Toast.makeText(Admin_Usuarios.this, "Usuario Criado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    );
}
```